# is it possible to assign dynamic value from request-path to `table` attribute for FormHandler gramex-config entry?

Tags: gramex

ref to [FormHandler-param-doc](https://learn.gramener.com/guide/formhandler/#formhandler-parameters)
below is the sample gramex-config snippet:
`dburl: postgresql://$db_name:$db_name@localhost:5432/$db_name`

```
  data_filter:
    pattern: /$YAMLURL/data_filter/(\w+)
    handler: FormHandler
    kwargs:
      url: $dburl
      table: {_0}
      modify: data_filter.by_month_date(data)
```

Is it possible to assign value dynamically for `table` attribute from part of request-URL path?
for a sample request like: 
`/data_filter/prod_rec_20?S_CODE=20&D_CODE=322&Market_Code=10753&Crop_Code=106`
Getting the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gramex\handlers\formhandler.py", line 157, in get
    result[key] = yield val
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 425, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gramex\data.py", line 247, in filter
    raise ValueError('No table: or query: specified')
ValueError: No table: or query: specified
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Please see https://learn.gramener.com/guide/formhandler/#formhandler-parameters

You can specify `table: '{_0}'`. Then `/data_filter/?table=prod_rec_20` would work.

`table: {_0}` without the quotes won't work, though. YAML interprets the `{}` as an object. You need to quote the `'{_0}'` for this to work. (I tested it, and it's working fine.